# Perform sql operations for this special case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Sir,

I am facing a problem and it is shown below:
I want to perform where opertion on the output of $this->db->select('*')->from('table'); only when cond1 satisfies

```
 $result = $this->db->select('*')->from('table');
 if(cond1)
 {
  I want to perform $result->where(); operation
 }
```

Is it possible and i so what is the exact syntax to do it

Comment: i didn't get your question

Comment: Its like i want to perform where operation only when a certain condtion satisfies

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
if ($cond1)
    $this->db->where(...)

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You can't do this: $result[]=$this->db->where(...)->get()->result(); in the foreach, Normally, when an Active Record call is completed, all stored information is reset for the next call. With caching, you can prevent this reset, and reuse information easily. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching

Comment: this one really helped me a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

`$con1` is should be a variable and it should has a value or Null. `$con1` like a Boolean.1 or 0 .if 1(true) happening it'll execute the  if block if not it'll execute the else block.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to run *two different queries*. Assuming that `$cond1` is not dependent upon `$result` (in which case all bets are off), you can do something like

```
if(cond1)
    $result = $this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where(...);
else
    $result = $this->db->select('*')->from('table');
```